# Overheating device with random apps spiking CPU usage

Tags: battery, cpu, xiaomi-redmi-note-4g

Few days ago my phone has started overheating and burning through the battery like crazy. I don't use it too much, and it used to last 1.5-2 days, now it's dead in 6 hours.

I've installed [System monitor lite](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cgollner.systemmonitor.lite%20System%20Monitor%20Lite) and it's showing that several of my cores are constantly at extremely high usage (over 80%), and various regular applications like Gmail and LinkedIn are shown spiking the CPU up to 20% each. I expected a single app to be doing something stupid, and after seeing which one it is, it would be simple to just remove it, but that's not the case. It turns out that a bunch of regular apps that I haven't opened in days are going crazy.

Here are some screenshots:

[image: All cores]
[image: Apps 1]
[image: Apps 2]
[image: Apps 4]

So, any suggestions besides doing factory reset?

### The phone in question is Xiaomi Redmi Note 4 running original MIUI without root.

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things:

- Applications that show running processes are only able to show the user processes (meaning no kernel processes)
- Android gives more priority to the application in the foreground (the one you are currently seeing). When you open the the task manager, the other processes are being capped. The measuring you are trying to do influences the results.

If you can provide more details by measuring externally with one of these:

1. **Try installing Android Studio**:[image: android studio]
2. **Post the Log Cat results**: [image: LogCat]
3. **Or use the Android Debug Bridge** ([adb](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb)) with `adb logcat` – you can view your Android device’s log.

With one of these you can actually profile your running Android phone over a USB connection.

I don't think anyone can give you a complete direct answer without some more information, except if maybe they had the exact same model number and issue.

Answer (score 0):

looking like you are on Chinese variant of RN4 with mediatek deca-core processor

If you feel like your phone is using too much cpu power than it is not the case [image showing cpu usage of asus zenfone max pro m1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyUOo.jpg)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyUOo.jpg)
here you can give a look at my device cpu usage. all 8 cores are working on a high frequency but still i am getting  a great battery backup. so definitely it is not looking like a issue in cpu.
u can try resetting your device or can take help from a xiaomi care.

Comment: I have 2 of these exact same phones, and as you can see from the second one, it's running cold compared to the first one: https://imgur.com/a/59u13EG. 7/10 cores are offline, and others are running fairly low, no app is using more than 2%-3% of CPU.

Comment: did you updated your phone recently looking like a software issue and pls check cpu usages with another apps too and check whether results are same or different.

Comment: here in my case both apps are showing different results